# JavaFx 2.0 + EJB + Netbeans - Runtime Exception

Tags: exception, netbeans, runtime, ejb, javafx-2

please,

I wrote a test app in JavaFx 2.0 + EJB in the Netbeans IDE and I got a problem running this app outside netbeans.

I have a form using FXML and an action of this form runs a EJB method. I am using the Glassfish Server.

When I run this test app on netbeans it works perfectly, but when I run the app outside of Netbeans like jnlp or in the browser ... the app can't access the EJB methods. I couldn't see the error message in webstart or in the browser. So, I ask:

1) How can I see the error message in a web start or in the browser? (like javaws test-app.jnlp)
2) I guess the error occurs because of classpath issues. (I need gf-client.jar and javaee-api-6.0.jar in the classpath in order the app works). How can I assure these jars are in the classpath?

Sorry by my english.

Thanks,

Cleber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. to see errors from jnlp you need to enable Java Console:

   Control Panel - Java Properties - Advanced - Java Console - Enable Console
2. for jnlp case all external libs should be stated in jnlp file. Usually NetBeans do it for you, but you can debug this case by reviewing Java Console output.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you for the answer. Now, like I've suspected, despite the javaws load the libs, I still got the message: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory]

Comment: this class is from J2EE installation, see http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory . It maybe included into `NetBeans + J2EE` installation so your app works from NetBeans. Try to add `appserv-rt.jar` manually to your project.

Comment: Thank you. I've discovered that if I just include the appserv-rt.jar I neither need of gf-client.jar in the project library, otherwise it still doesn't work outside Netbeans. I see in the appserv-rt.jar lib dependencies that it depends of gf-client.jar, but I don't need to include this last in the project library, because I guess netbeans tracks witch libraries the project needs.

I believe now, if someone could explain how to deploy / configure an  application client in a remote computer, I guess it will solve my problem. I'll be trying, I hope soon found a solution and I'll post here.

Comment: I've found the solution months ago, finally. To run a app-client without problems, you must follow the the steps showed in the link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4337/beaem/index.html . The oracle articles are excellent.